# Testing with spring configuration and Mocking objects

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am using a spring configuration in testing like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/spring/config.xml" })
```

Let's say I'm testing a service that depends on other services and a repository. Using the `@ContextConfiguration` these beans will be created and autowired into the service I am testing.

Is it considered better to mock these dependencies and repositories? When creating and loading a test configuration as done currently, a problem in a dependency could cause the test to fail, so I am not really only testing that one service but the other dependencies as well.

Should these dependencies be mocked in the unit test (since you are only supposed to test the functionality of that class and not its dependencies) but instantiated and wired in during integration tests?

Comment: Yes, that is how you should do it. No need of spring context in unit tests.

Comment: Well, I am not a big fan of mocking everything around :) If you have nicely grained objects (that peform some operation together) then I do not see anything wrong in testing them together. Then you can use Spring in your tests. Write your tests as a specification of what is expected to happen when some functionality gets executed. Don't write tests that will reflect the classes and methods 1:1. It is not the way to go.

Comment: @RohitJain That's what I thought but wasn't sure. Thanks for your help :-).